# Sticky CSS setting do not work because the ancestor div do not fill the available height

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have 2 columns where the content of the right column is shorter. At the top of the right column I want to have a sticky row. However the sticky row scrolls out of the screen at the end of the right column. This is the code:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="column1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
  <div id="column2">
    <div id="column2-head">
      This should be sticky
    </div>
    <div id="column-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the styling:

```
#column1 {
  width: 20%;
}
#column2 {
  width: 80%;
}
#column1, #column2 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
#column2-head {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

See [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nagyt234/d28um5tk/22/).

So the question is, ho can I achieve, that column2 height is set to the available space without explicitly set the height. I've tried to set "height: 100; overflow: hidden" for column2, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use flex:

```css
#container{
    display: flex;  
}
#column1 {
  width: 20%;
}
#column2 {
  width: 80%;
}

#column2-head {
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="column1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
  <div id="column2">
    <div id="column2-head">
      This should be sticky
    </div>
    <div id="column-content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```